# I can't see the continue button on screen (Ubuntu installation)

Tags: system-installation, ubuntu-sdk

I am stuck at who are you screen . I can partially see the back button but not the continue button .  https://i.stack.imgur.com/BcAnC.jpg

Comment: You can move any window by locating the cursor somewhere in the window, press the Alt key and move the cursor (with the mouse or touchpad). This way it is possible to move the window until you see the continue button.